# Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/lib/breadcrumb'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Trying to compile a project and being greeted with

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\TokenFarm.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\sean\AppData\Local\Temp\test--17472-6fYHF170F1H9
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/lib/Breadcrumb'
Require stack:
```

I've tried manually installing the package with

```
npm install --save Breadcrumbs
```

But I can't seem to find the correct link to download the library

Is there a way to install an older version of node because I believe the repo I'm cloning from is from a few years ago so there could be some dependency issues going on.

Comment: You can install older version of node if you wanted to. You can also [install an older version of an npm package](https://nodejs.dev/learn/install-an-older-version-of-an-npm-package) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to downgrade your node version. It appears your `react-bootstrap` has been updated with a major release, without updating related references.

To fix this, either downgrade your library version as suggested by Drew Reese, or just fix your imports.

If you look over the [library codebase](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/master/src), you can see you should now import your components through `react-bootstrap/src/Breadcrumb` instead.